# PHP can't exec xcodebuild, how to fix it?

Tags: php, bash, shell, xcodebuild

I can't call `Xcodebuild` with PHP, using the 'nobody' user—nothing happens.
All the directories have `777` permissions.

Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly are you "calling" it? Post some actual code.

Comment: i tried from the php like that: `/user....../xcodebuild -project /user......project/text.xcodeproj`. And saved it as **bash script** and calling to the bash script with `shell_exec`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it build properly from the command line?

Comment: What is the return value of xcodebuild when executing it from PHP?

Comment: if its help: **69**- when i call to `xcodebuild` from his dir **...\xcode\bin\xcodebuil**. I copied it and call it from **\users** and got returned error **5**.